# How to perform conditional operation inside XPath?

Tags: java, xpath, conditional-statements

I want to compare if the text is '`CEO`' or '`Chief Operating Office`' inside a **Xpath**  :

```
 String ceo=(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),
            'CEO' or 'Chief Operating Officer')]//following::dd[1]"))).getText();
 System.out.println(ceo);
```

But the code above returns something else.

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: grammar fixed

tag selenium removed

tag condition added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xpath("//*[contains(text(),'CEO') or contains(text(),'Chief Operating Officer')])
```

`contains()` return a bool value, you should use it like:

```
bool or bool >>>> contains() or contains()
```